# What is this pattern's name?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I have written a few template classes as part of a larger template class. One allows me to include or exclude member variables from a class. Another allows me to produce either the passed template class parameter or a placeholder that NOPs instead.

These allow classes to use their own template parameters to include or exclude data members through a single very generic class definition, and the operations provide an interface that prevents type mismatch issues.

This code sample shows my implementation in use as I assume it will be easier to recognise in action (the classes relating to the pattern have been called "ghost").

```
typedef int field1type, field2type, field3type;

template <bool field1exists, bool field2exists, bool field3exists>
struct GhostShowcase
{
  typename Ghost<int, field1exists>::type intField;
  typename Ghost<float, field2exists>::type floatField;
  typename Ghost<char, field3exists>::type charField;
};

GhostShowcase<true,false,true> foo; // has int and char fields
                                    // but an unusable float field
GhostShowcase<true,true,true> bar; // has all fields usable
```

The samples below show how to use operators with the types derived from ghost classes. The testing function `printAll()` uses `ghostStaticOperator()` to call static functions in a class derived from `GhostStaticOperation`. This class is either the class that was passed as a template parameter to `GhostStaticOperation` or an automatically generated class which has a static function with the same signature but does nothing. The class chosen is based on the boolean template parameter `exists`. in `main()` two calls are made; the first passes the template parameter true and the second passes false.

These samples show compilable source (in g++ 4.5.2, with -std=c++0x set). This file can be named anything.

```
#include "ghost.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace Aryana;
using namespace std;

struct PrintingOperator : public std::unary_function<int, void>
{
  static inline void operation(int toPrint)
  {cout << toPrint;}
};

struct IncrementOperator : public std::unary_function<int&, void>
{
  static inline void operation(int& toIncrement)
  {++toIncrement;}
};

template <bool exists>
void printAll()
{
  typedef GhostStaticOperator<PrintingOperator, exists> printClass;
  typedef GhostStaticOperator<IncrementOperator, exists> incrClass;

  typename Ghost<int, exists>::type ghostObject;
  cout << "using ghost printer: ";
  ghostStaticOperation<printClass>(ghostObject);
  cout << "\nusing ghost incrementor...\n";
  ghostStaticOperation<incrClass>(ghostObject);
  cout << "using ghost printer: ";
  ghostStaticOperation<printClass>(ghostObject);
  cout << "\nfinished\n";
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  cout << "ghost operation with exists=true:\n";
  printAll<true>();
  cout << "ghost operation with exists=false:\n";
  printAll<false>();
}
```

This sample should be named "ghost.h" and put in the same directory as the previous file.

```
typedef char ghost_null_argument[0];
typedef void ghost_null_return;

template <class S, bool exists>
class Ghost;

template <class S, bool exists>
class GhostOperator;

template <class S, bool exists>
class GhostStaticOperator;

template <class S>
class Ghost<S, false>
{
  Ghost(); // private constructor to prevent instantiation
 public:
  typedef ghost_null_argument type;
  typedef S original_type;
};

template <class S>
class Ghost<S, true>
{
  Ghost(); // private constructor to prevent instantiation
 public:
  typedef S type;
  typedef S original_type;
};

template <class S, bool exists>
class GhostOperator;

template <class S>
class GhostStaticOperator<S, false>
{
  GhostStaticOperator(); // private constructor to prevent instantiation
 public:
  typedef ghost_null_return result_type;
  typedef ghost_null_argument argument_type;
  struct operator_type
  {
    inline static result_type operation(argument_type){};
  };
};

template <class S>
class GhostStaticOperator<S, true>
{
  GhostStaticOperator(); // private constructor to prevent instantiation
 public:
  typedef S operator_type;
  typedef typename operator_type::result_type result_type;
  typedef typename operator_type::argument_type argument_type;
};

// must define argument_type and result_type in the operator class
// result_type will be ghost_null_argument if the class is ghosting
template <class S>
inline
typename S::result_type ghostStaticOperation(typename S::argument_type argument)
{
  return S::operator_type::operation(argument);
}
```

Comment: This is not at all a short or self-contained example. I have no idea what this code does.

Comment: @DeadMG I do not feel I can shorten the large source files, but I will try to add to the question. Please explain in what context you would like the example.

Comment: Template metaprogramming similar to traits class? Seriously though I'm with DeadMG this is information overload. Try to make a concise statement of the design and you may answer your own question by doing so.

Comment: I doubt that when you can not make it more concise and understandable, it is any pattern at all.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone - if one of you answers with "not a pattern" I will accept. I knew it was quite big when I posted. I just thought it was a really useful approach to what I am currently working on and was also very generic, so someone else had probably implemented this already in a library I could use. Thanks again for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it's the "bug" pattern. `char[0]` is not a valid member type.

More seriously, normally we use SFINAE to directly check for members that might or might not exist. That avoids the whole `Ghost<T, bool>` template.

Comment: Oh haha I thought I'd found a nice little hack that allowed me to add members that added zero width to the containing class. I guess it's not portable then, even though it compiles fine for me. The reason I want this member is to generate classes that either contain or exclude members based on their own template parameters, if you could give me an example of how to use SFINAE to generate classes then I would be grateful.

Comment: @fuseinabowl : You don't use SFINAE to generate classes. You generally use it to exclude certain template instantiations, e.g. from an overload set. A common pattern is to have a `member(...)` and a `member(int i = T::x)` method. If `T::x` exists, the second method can be instantiated and will hide the first.

Comment: I understand that, but I am using these ghost derived types to construct several classes from a single template class definition. Is there a way to decide whether to include a member variable without writing specializations for each combination of bool include flags?

Comment: @fuseinabowl: You might be reinventing tuples there. (§20.4 in C++11)